Will there also be this benefit
Will going to thirumandakunnu and worshipping the angadipuram devi in mallapuram in kerala also help those with mangala dosha- have been there before also.I have some mangala dosha and am planning on getting a mangal yantra for my house.Replies are appreciated- this will make me feel good more.thank you.
